# Count Days Since Last Launch?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would I count the days that have past since the last time the user brought the iOS application from the background into the foreground?

I would like to use NSDate to take the current date in which the user closed the application but then where would I go from here, create another NSDate when the application is reopened and compare it to? Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `NSUserDefaults` and `NSDate` for that.

When your app starts it should try to read that "firstLaunchDate" from the `defaults`.

If that date isn't there (nil) that means your app is launched the first time => therefore it's time to store the current date to the defaults and next time your app starts you get a valid date from the defaults and you can do your math with it.

*search SO for more and you will get enough code to proceed*

Answer (score 0):

if you have last time already, you can use it.

```
NSDate *lastDate = [NSDate distantPast];
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

NSTimeInterval interval = [today timeIntervalSinceDate:lastDate];
//    interval is second
NSLog(@"%f days", interval/(60*60*24));
```

You may get floating number of the days.

Comment: This is *not* the correct way to compute the number of days, because a day may have more or less than (60*60*24) seconds. (Think of daylight saving time.)

Comment: ah! @MartinR is right! The difference time must be calculated.